# How to use Error Report from GCE with Docker and Django?

Tags: python, django, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-error-reporting

I'm running Django on a compute engine using Docker. I would like to know how to check the error in the Error Report when the application encounters an error like Cloud run.

I'm looking at how to set up an Error Report in Python. https://github.com/googleapis/python-error-reporting/tree/main/samples/snippets/fluent_on_compute

Looking at this sample, it looks like I need to raise an exception and run `report (traceback.format_exc ())` to use the Error Report.

[Sample code](https://github.com/googleapis/python-error-reporting/blob/main/samples/snippets/fluent_on_compute/main.py)

```
def simulate_error():
    fluent.sender.setup('myapp', host='localhost', port=24224)

    def report(ex):
        data = {}
        data['message'] = '{0}'.format(ex)
        data['serviceContext'] = {'service': 'myapp'}
        # ... add more metadata
        fluent.event.Event('errors', data)

    # report exception data using:
    try:
        # simulate calling a method that's not defined
        raise NameError
    except Exception:
        report(traceback.format_exc())
```

When I run Django, I get an error other than using `try: execpt`.

How can I display such errors in the Error Report?

Please let me know if there is any good way. thank you.

Comment: If you properly configure the error reporter in your project, you will be able to see the errors in error reporting in the GCP console. https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/viewing-errors or do you have another kind of issue using error reporter?

Comment: @IsmaelClementeAguirre Hi! I can see Error Report from `report(traceback.format_exc())`, however error will happen outside of `try: except`. How can I catch the error by Error Reporting?

Comment: According to official documentation, you can Set up error reporting on GCP using the error reporter API or by logging to cloud logging, which one are you trying to use? You can send error reports to Error Reporting from Python applications by using the Error Reporting library for Python.

Comment: Error Reporting is integrated with some Google Cloud services, such as App Engine, Compute Engine, and Google Kubernetes Engine. Error Reporting displays the errors that are logged to Cloud Logging by applications running on those services. More in this link: https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/setup/python

Answer (score 0):

Django provides an option to define [custom exception handler](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling).
You can define custom exception handler as show below,

```
from google.cloud import error_reporting
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler

# Initialize Error reporting client
client = error_reporting.Client()

def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    # Call REST framework's default exception handler first,
    # to get the standard error response.
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)

    # Send error to Error Reporting
    client.report(response)

    return response
```

In your settings file add the below configuration,

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'my_project.my_app.utils.custom_exception_handler'
}
```

To install google cloud error reporting library, use the below command

```
pip install google-cloud-error-reporting
```

For reference on setting up Error reporting in python, refer to [this](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/setup/python)

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I'm not using REST Framework. I'd like to catch error exception in `settings.py`, `urls.py` ,`views.py` and `models.py` files. How can I set like `EXCEPTION_HANDLER `? Or `EXCEPTION_HANDLER` works these files error?